# How this dictionary gets the data?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, for-loop, if-statement

Can anyone explain me this ? This function takes a string and counts the frequency of each word and returns a dictionary with word, frequency. I don't understand how the dictionary gets data.

```
def count_words(text):
    text = text.split()
    words = {}
    for i in text:
        if i in words:
            words[i] += 1
        else:
            words[i] = 1
    return words
```

Comment: Python is one of the most readable languages. What exactly are you not understanding from this code?

Comment: When this function `count_words()` gets called, it takes in the parameter `text`. text is just a list of words. Your loop place an occurence of that word in a dictionary and increments every time the word appears in the list again after the first occurence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With comments:

```
def count_words(text):
    # Split the text up into words
    text = text.split()

    # Initialise an empty dictionary
    words = {}

    # For each word in the text
    for i in text:
        # If we already have the word in our dictionary, add 1 to the counter
        if i in words:
            words[i] += 1
        # Otherwise, add the word to our dictionary with the counter 1
        else:
            words[i] = 1
    # Return the dictionary of words and counts
    return words
```

Answer (score 1):

The data comes from the argument text.

```
def count_words(text):
    text = text.split()
    words = {}
    for i in text:
        if i in words:
            words[i] += 1
        else:
            words[i] = 1
    return words
```

So when you do `count_words("Hello World")`, you are assigning "Hello World" to the `text argument`, that becomes the data.

Another way is to assign the data to a variable before passing it to the function call:

```
text = "Hello World"  # This is the data
count_words(text)
```